# How can I export a tsibble to excel, retaining the time index as character format e.g. "2014 Q4" rather than a number

Tags: r, date, time-series, export, tsibble

My end user wants an excel workbook that includes the time series index in format YYYY Qx e.g. 1998 Q1 but whatever way I export my quarterly time series tsibble to excel the index column always ends up being a number - I think the number represents the number of days from 1 January 1970. I would like to find a way to do this.

I looked at Rob Hyndman's function on https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/ts2csv/ to write a tsibble to csv and this works fine (not sure if Rob still checks his page - but will not that I have asked here to avoid doubling up). Below is the write to csv, which works well and the index has "1998 Q1" style formatting.

```
library(fpp2)
readr::write_csv(tsibble::as_tsibble(visnights), "visnights.csv")
```

But I can't find a way of exporting that retains the time index format when exporting to excel.
If I use something like the code below the first data element in the index column is a number - 10227 - instead of 1998 Q1

```
library(writexl)
write_xlsx(tsibble::as_tsibble(visnights), path = "visnights.xlsx", col_names = TRUE)
```

One more example - using pivot_longer = FALSE

```
library(tsibble)
library(writexl)
z <- ts(matrix(rnorm(300), 100, 3), start = c(1961, 1), frequency = 12)
exp <- as_tsibble(z, pivot_longer = FALSE)
write_xlsx(exp, path = "exp.xlsx", col_names = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could convert it to a tibble (instead of a tsibble) as this allows you to convert the index column to a character using `mutate()` from dplyr:

```r
library(tsibble)
library(writexl)
z <- ts(matrix(rnorm(300), 100, 3), start = c(1961, 1), frequency = 12)
exp_z <- as_tsibble(z, pivot_longer = FALSE) %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(index = as.character(index))
write_xlsx(exp_z, path = "exp.xlsx", col_names = TRUE)
```

Note that, I've renamed your variable here as it's bad practice to create variables with the same name as functions.

Comment: Thanks nrennie. That's perfect. Very simple, but much appreciated when one is stuck.

Also thanks for the advice on best practise. Being new to R I think I need to go and study best practise guides\ other's work.